# Multichannel Audio recording in Android

Tags: android, audio, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord

I have a multichannel microphone connected to an android phone (pixel 3) through usb. I'm trying to use [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) API for recording audio. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to setup multichannel recording with MediaRecorder even though [Android USB audio](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/usb#channels) documentation seems to say it allows multichannel input. I know recording multi channel audio is possible, as there are apps that already do that (see [ntrack](https://ntrack.com/android-multitrack-studio-manual.php#connecting-your-external-sound-card-usb-audio)). I'm trying to figure out how to do this and hoping it doesn't involve writing usb driver (like these [developers](http://www.extreamsd.com/index.php/technology/usb-audio-driver)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see your microphones as separate input devices using `audioService.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS)` then you can use the AAudio API (preferably using [Oboe](https://github.com/google/oboe) library) to access each of these microphones by opening stream for each.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.